# Root in a splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

[image]

For this question, where does $(-3^{1/3}+-(3^{1/6})^5i)/2$ come from?

Comment: The nonreal cubic roots of unity are $\omega = (-1 + \sqrt{3}i)/2, \omega^{2} = (-1 - \sqrt{3}i)/2$, so compute (e.g.) $\omega \sqrt[3]{3}$.

Comment: Isn't the complex cube root of 3 is just $3^{1/3}$?

Comment: $3^{1/3}=\sqrt[3] 3$ is the real cube root of $3$. The complex cube roots of $3$ are $\omega \cdot \sqrt[3] 3$ and $\omega^2 \cdot \sqrt[3] 3$.

Comment: Is there any formula for finding complex roots?

Comment: The $n$ solutions to $x^n-r$ where r is a positive real number and $\omega$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity is $\sqrt[n] r$, and then $\omega \cdot \sqrt[n] r$, and then $\omega^2 \cdot \sqrt[n] r$, all the way up to, $\omega^{n-1} \cdot \sqrt[n] r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you solve $x^3-3$, one solutions you get is $\sqrt[3] 3$. To get the other solutions, first, factor out $x-\sqrt[3] 3$ from the polynomial:

$$x^3-3=x^3-\sqrt[3] 3 x^2+\sqrt[3] 3 x^2-(\sqrt[3] 3)^2 x+(\sqrt[3] 3)^2 x-3=(x-\sqrt[3] 3)(x^2+\sqrt[3] 3 x+(\sqrt[3] 3)^2)$$

Now, for the quadratic, using the quadratic formula, we get:

$$\frac{-\sqrt[3] 3 \pm \sqrt{(\sqrt[3] 3)^2-4(\sqrt[3] 3)^2}}{2}=\frac{-\sqrt[3] 3 \pm \sqrt{-3(\sqrt[3] 3)^2}}{2}=\frac{-\sqrt[3] 3 \pm (\sqrt[6] 3)^5 i}{2}$$

Comment: So this is equivalent to find the complex roots for the polynomial $(x^3-3)/(x-3^{1/3})$? And in general, we first find the division of the minimal polynomial and $(x-complex root)$

Comment: This only works for cubics. If you know the cubic formula, you can also do this for quartics and if you know the quartic formula, you can also do this for quintics. However, if you're trying to solve $x^n-r$ for any arbitrary integer $n$ and complex $r$, then it's a lot easier to put $r$ in polar form and then use [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) to find the roots.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, why is $\Bbb Q(2^{1/2})$ is an extension field for $\Bbb Q$? I think $\Bbb Q(2^{1/2})$ belongs to $\Bbb Q$? Why is it the other way around?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$. This is because both fields contain all the rational numbers, but $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$ has $\sqrt 2$ while $\Bbb{Q}$ does not. Therefore, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt 2)$ is an extension field of the rational numbers that includes the rational numbers and $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Oh I think I mistaken rational numbers with complex numbers... Thanks!!